# Getting error in multiple Pivot automation where I've to select account and year

Tags: vba

```vb
 Dim pt As PivotTable
 For Each pt In ws.PivotTables
      With pt
         With .PivotFields("Root Account")
              .ClearAllFilters
              .CurrentPage = rootAccount
         End With
         With .PivotFields("Year")
              .CurrentPage = year  **GETTING ERROR IN THIS LINE**
         End With
      End With
 Next pt
```

Comment: Please don't post questions which are just a title and some code.  Tell us what you're trying to do, and tell us *exactly* what the problem is you're having with your code.  If you get an error, what error is it?  What is `year` in your posted code?  It doesn't appear anywhere else in the code.